# How do I fix NodeJS version being wrong?

Tags: node.js

```
Error: The module '\\?\C:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Content\Scripts\node_modules\jitterbuffer\build\Release\node-jitterbuffer.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: try to remove package.lock.json and npm install

Comment: Same thing sadly.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Compile (or get a compiled binary of) the module for the Node.js version you're using.
- Use the version of Node.js the package was compiled to work with.

The instructions for compilation (if they exist) are usually in the package's repository.